# Stripe change payment method in customer portal not letting me put zip code in alphanumeric

Tags: stripe-payments

When entering a debit card inside stripe while signing up we enter card information and billing address. Now in here, we can enter zip code/postal code and we can enter this in alphanumeric format.

[image]

Now inside the customer portal if the user wants to update his/her billing information then stripe asks for zip code and in here I am not able to enter alphanumeric instead its only allows me to enter in number format

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who lands on this page looking for the answer
This wasn't an issue. Basically, postal code will automatically expect the code to be from the same country of the credit card origin

So if I am entering a card from Canada then zip format will be Canada